# Probability density function from known density function

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function

Suppose I want to compute new density function $Z$, $Z= min(X_1,2X_1-X_2)$, where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent exponential distributions with $\lambda$. I have looked into [Finding the density for $\min\{X, Y\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1817373/finding-the-density-for-min-x-y) and in their case, $X, Y $ are independent, so they can split the cdf into a product. But here, I don't think  $X_1,2X_1-X_2$ are independent because of the $2X_1-X_2$ How would I tackle this? I also know that the sum of two exponential distributions is a gamma distribution but I don't know if they are independent so I cannot proceed. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observing  that $3>2$ and $X_1,X_2 \geq 0$ it results to me that

$$3X_1\geq 2X_1-X_2$$

$\forall x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R}^+$

Thus

$$Z=2X_1-X_2$$

With usual transformation procedures the distribution of Z can be derived without particular problems

---

EDIT:

Let's use the definition:

$$ \bbox[yellow,5px,border:2px solid red]
{
\mathbb{P}[Z>z]=\mathbb{P}[min(X,2X-Y)>z]=\mathbb{P}[X>z;Y<2X-z]
\
}
$$

Do a drawing and derive the region to integrate $f_{XY}(x,y)$ to find $1-F_Z(z)$

---

**sketch of solution:**

FIrst observe that $Z \in \mathbb{R}$

If $Z\leq 0$ you can integrate the following region

$$\mathbb{P}[Z>z]=\int_0^{\infty}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\Bigg[\int_0^{2x-z}\lambda e^{-\lambda y} dy \Bigg]dx=1-\frac{1}{3}e^{\lambda z}$$

Thus $F_Z(z)=\frac{1}{3}e^{\lambda z}$

If $Z>0$ you integrate the following region

$$\mathbb{P}[Z>z]=\int_z^{\infty}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\Bigg[\int_0^{2x-z}\lambda e^{-\lambda y} dy \Bigg]dx=e^{-\lambda z}-\frac{1}{3}e^{-2\lambda z}$$

Putting the result together you find the CDF of Z

$$  F_Z(z) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{3}e^{\lambda z},  & z\leq 0 \\
1-e^{-\lambda z}+\frac{1}{3}e^{-2\lambda z}, & z>0
\end{cases}$$

This is the drawing of $F_Z(z)$ for a fixed $\lambda=1$

[image]

As you can see, this is a nice CDF.

To find the desired pdf, just take the derivative of F

Comment: My bad, it is $Z=min(X_1,2X_1-X_2)$ (Original question is $Z=min(3X_1,2X_1-X_2)$)

Comment: @JayEstrera : I added some hints in my answer. I set $X_1=X$ and $X_2=Y$ to simplify the notation....I hope now it is clear how to proceed (let me know)

Comment: If I integrate the joint pdf $f(x,y)$ over the region of $X>z, Y<2X−z$ I would get a new area under $f(x,y)$, and would that new area be the CDF of Z? Why is it 1-$F_z(z)$?

Comment: @JayEstrera:  $1-F_Z=P(Z>z)$ then take its complement to find $F_Z=P(Z\leq z)$. Remember you are working on the min of 2 rv. Let me know if it is clear otherwise tell me and I will solve it in details...finding the time to do the calculation (I'm working)

Comment: It is fine, thank you for the hints! I am just curious how does integrating $f(x,y)$ over that region gives $P(Z>z)$ (didn't see this on my notes)

Comment: @JayEstrera : added a sketch with all details for your solution.

Comment: @JayEstrera :  if you read the first row of my EDIT, I started from the definition of $P(Z>z)$ and I derived a region where to integrate...(now highlighted)

Comment: thanks you for time!